# Missing FROM-clause entry for table "token"

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm using NestJs with TypeORM (Postgres database) and I would like to delete my expired tokens from the database at regular intervals. This is my token entity:

```
@Entity('Token')
export class Token extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public encoding: string;

  @Column()
  public expiresOn: Date;
}
```

I want to delete every token from the database that has expired. So the `expiresOn` returns an older date than the current date.

When I call this

```
    await this.tokensRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('token')
      .delete()
      .from(Token) // I also tried it with 'token'
      .where('token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate: new Date() })
      .execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
query: DELETE FROM "Token" WHERE token.expiresOn <= $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["2020-01-11T16:37:21.964Z"]
query failed: DELETE FROM "Token" WHERE token.expiresOn <= $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["2020-01-11T16:37:21.964Z"]
error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "token"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:403:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 116,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '27',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '3240',
  routine: 'errorMissingRTE'
}
(node:18572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "token"
    at new QueryFailedError (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:145:17)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:214:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/matthias/Projects/nest-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:128:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
```

If you would like to have a look at the repository, there it is

https://github.com/matthiashermsen/nest-api/blob/master/src/authentications/expired-tokens-removal.service.ts#L60

If you would like to try out the NestJs API this this my .env file configuration

```
SERVER_PORT = 3000

DATABASE_TYPE = postgres
DATABASE_HOST = localhost
DATABASE_PORT = 5432
DATABASE_USERNAME = postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD = postgres
DATABASE_NAME = api
DATABASE_LOGGING = true
DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE = true

NODE_ENV = development

AUTHENTICATION_SALT_ROUNDS = 12
TOKEN_SECRET = secret
TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS = 36000
EXPIRED_TOKEN_REMOVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enclose an identifier in quotes in SQL, it must be written exactly as it is stored. The name `"Token"` is not equal to `token`. You probably should change you entity declaration to `@Entity('token')`.

Comment: If I may ask a question. The OP also uses `'User'` for this entity and this seems to work as you can see here https://github.com/matthiashermsen/nest-api/blob/master/src/users/user.entity.ts and here https://github.com/matthiashermsen/nest-api/blob/master/src/users/users.repository.ts#L23 So should all entities be lowercase or should you just change the query to `await this.tokensRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('Token')
      .delete()
      .from(Token)
      .where('Token.expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate: new Date() })
      .execute();` ?

Comment: and btw. is the Entity alias optional for the entity class? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#what-is-entity So maybe one shouldn't even use aliases to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by removing the name from the entity decorator in my token entity.

```
@Entity()
export class Token extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  public encoding: string;

  @Column()
  public expiresOn: Date;
}
```

Next I took the sample from the docs https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/delete-query-builder.md#delete-using-query-builder and created this delete query which seems to work fine for me

```
await this.tokensRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .delete()
  .from(Token)
  .where('expiresOn <= :currentDate', { currentDate: new Date() })
  .execute();
```